# Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 7 - Mission Impossible?

Tags: installation, windows-7, wubi, 13.10, eeepc

I just want to install Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 7 HP on my EeePC 1215N. I can't do it when Windows 7 is booted up (wubi.exe hasn't got that option), so I booted it from USB key.

Everything's loaded, I double-click Install Ubuntu. I click 'Next >', then I choose that I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7.

And the machine restarts. Not resets. Restarts.
X server's killed immediately, I can see the console only.

What do I have to do now?

Comment: Are you at a console right now then?

Answer (score 0):

A first step would be to ask windows to check the filesystem of the partition that you are trying to modify. The partitioning tool has a hard time dealing with errors on the disk. When you are booted into windows

[How-To Geek's Windows check disk tool guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/guide-to-using-check-disk-in-windows-vista/)

Windows will continue to work even if the file system has errors but the ubuntu partition tool can have a wide range of issues when the Windows file system has errors. We have done mass dual boot installs for students here on the university and we always run into this issue.  Give installing a try again after you run the Windows check disk utility.